# How to know if the loops can be parallelized for multithreading with the help of openmp?

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have a nested loop. i would like to know if the outer and the inner loops can be parallelized with the help of openmp?

```
for (col = n-1; col >= 0; col--) {
    x[col] /= A[col][col];
    for (row = 0; row < col; row++)
        x[row] -= A[row][col] * x[col];
}
```

I think the outer loop can be paralelized as the inner loop depends only on the fixed value of the the column or col.

Comment: As for the outer loop, the computed value of `x[i]` depends on the computed value of `x[i+1]`, so it sure looks like it needs to be computed sequentially to me.  The _inner_ loop however, can be computed in parallel. Not sure you'll save much in doing so though, it's such a tiny amount of work.

Comment: @Wyck - Yes thats the correct answer, but I did not quite understand your explanation. 
x[col] does not depend on x[col+1]. If col =3(if n=4) then x[3],x[2],x[1],x[0] are all calculated in its individual loop iteration as the value of col iterates. May be I am going wrong somewhere.

Comment: Imagine you are on the iteration where `col == 5`.  and `row == 4`.  You are performing `x[4] -= A[4][5] * x[5]`.  You have `x[4]` on the left hand side of the `=` and `x[5]` on the right hand side of the `=`.  So `x[4]` depends on `x[5]`.  It means that `x[5]` must be computed **before** `x[4]`.  And, in general, `x[i]` depends on `x[i+1]` (as it was computed in the iteration of the outer loop where `col` = `i+1`).  So the values of x must be computed sequentially in descending order.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I analyzed your answer and I have seen that if we parallelize the outer loop then it is not a problem. If I consider your example above with col==5 and row==5, I understand that x[4]-=A[4]*A[5]*x[5]... so x[4] depends on x[5] but x[5] is already calculated in the above statement x[5] /=A[5][5]... so x[5] is always calculated in the current iteration. So every time the dependency is already calculated outside the inner loop...

Comment: You're missing an important aspect of mutability.  When you have `x += c` (which is just `x = x + c`) you are _mutating_ a variable.  To perform dependence analysis, you should replace all mutable symbols with immutable constants.  e.g. `x_1 = x_0 + c`.  The original value of `x` is denoted by `x_0`.  And if we want to modify `x` then we create a new symbol `x_1`, and if we want to modify `x` yet again, we create yet another new symbol `x_2`, incrementing the "generation number" after the underscore to track each modification to the mutable `x`, replacing them with _immutable_ `x_i` constants.

Comment: Another great way to quickly analyze whether or not it can be parallelized is:  if you can run the loop in the opposite direction (or in random order), it can be parallelized.  Your inner loop works fine if you reverse the direction of iteration.  But your outer loop breaks if you reverse the order of iteration because you have a loop dependence.  Which means, the state at the end of the loop is dependent on the order in which the iterations within the loop were executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sufficient condition (but not necessary!) of parallelizability is

- for each value of the loop variable
- only array locations with that index are changed.

In such a case iterations `i1` and `i2` can not write in conflicting locations, therefore the writes can be done in any order, therefore in parallel.

In your code the inner loop satisfies that condition; your outer *does not*. That's because the inner loop writes a whole bunch of indices, and not just `[col]`. So two different `col` values will all write to identical locations. You can sometimes fix that with an `atomic` directive, but that's 1. not good for performance 2. not even possible in your particular case because of the non-associativity of the operations you're doing.

Comment: I think atomic operations only solve the data race, but the result also depends on the order of the outer loop (because the order of division and subtractions cannot be interchanged).

Comment: @Laci You're absolutely right. I've amended my answer.